# Find Time Gaps in Records

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hi have a security camera that records in continuous mode.  It saves a record of its recordings to a sqlite database file into a few different files. I'm trying to find time gaps in the recordings.  The problem is that certain recording events overlap so I can't simply find the time difference between starttime and stoptime.  Here is the query I am currently using:

```
select b.id,  datetime(b.starttime, "-8 Hour") as starttime, datetime(b.stoptime, "-8 Hour") as endtime, b.recording_id
from blocks b, recordings a 
where b.recording_id = a.id and a.recording_type_id = 1 order by b.starttime asc
```

Here is an excerpt from a query where I sort by Starttime:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   starttime           endtime             recording_id  |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| ---- ------------------- ------------------- ------------  |
| 6824 2016-03-22 12:32:48 2016-03-22 12:38:08 389           |
| 6825 2016-03-22 12:38:08 2016-03-22 12:43:28 389           |
| 6826 2016-03-22 12:39:00 2016-03-22 12:41:10 418           |
| 6827 2016-03-22 12:43:28 2016-03-22 12:48:48 389           |
| 6828 2016-03-22 12:48:48 2016-03-22 12:54:08 389           |
| 6829 2016-03-22 12:54:08 2016-03-22 12:59:28 389           |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I get a time gap from ID 6826 to ID 6827 when in fact there isn't one.  ID 6825 lines up with ID 6827.

Any ideas how to make this work.  I thought about hammering each second of each day to test if it lies between any of the times and create a record that way but that's just brutish.

Comment: Add your query to your question so we can debug.   It sounds like you aren't considering Recording_Id in your logic.

Comment: That maybe the case but I still see a situation where there will be overlapping time.  If I for instance create a subquery that sorts first by recording_id how do I later collate that.  I'll still have an overlap to deal with.

Comment: Try to find `stoptime` values that cannot be found within all the available segments:

Comment: Please show what results you *want* to get.  Your results seem reasonable, although I suspect you just want `order by recording_id, timestamp`.

Comment: What Gordon said is the reason I asked.  Is this query your final query, and when you say you "get a gap", you just mean when you're eyeballing it?   Or is there a second query that needs to programmatically look for gaps?   And if so, please post THAT query.

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting problem. :-)

```
Select a.starTime as 'Coverage Gap Closed'
  From TableName a 
  Inner Join TableName b
    On a.startTime between b.startTime and b.endTime
      And a.PrimaryKey != b.PrimaryKey
```

This will identify any record that you have that did not start within the timeframe of another record and thus represents the end of a coverage gap.

I will leave it to the student to adjust this to find:

- The start time of all coverage.
- The end time of all coverage.
- The start and end times of gaps.